# ('...').each not a valid function for asp.net core mvc with jquery bundle

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017

Reposting this because I cannot find any answer that doesn't involve using Google's bundle or something else. Please tell me if I'm missing any detail so I'll add it. I have the whole jquery bundle included with VS referenced at the top of my _Layout...

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Here's the BundleConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
```

...but it is still telling me in this case that `.each` is not a function. What I'm missing or need to refer to the layout or BundleConfig? Why isn't `.each` a function that is a part of the jquery bundle that comes with Visual Studio 2017?

```
@Html.ListBox("Groups", null, new { size = 10, style = "width : 350px; max-width : 500px;", id = "grouplist" })
```

The whole context of my jquery:

```
    $('#savegroups').click(function () {
            var groupId = $('#groupId').val();
            var list = [];
            ('#grouplist').each(function (item) {
                list.append('{"groupId":"' + groupId + '","groupName":"' + item.value +'"}');
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/GroupCategories/EditGroups",
                data: JSON.stringify(list),
            });
   });
```

Error:

```
1:230 Uncaught TypeError: "#grouplist".each is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (1:230)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery:1)
    at HTMLInputElement.y.handle (jquery:1)
```

Comment: change **('#grouplist')** to **$('#grouplist')**

Comment: I tried that, it just skipped doing the whole loop at that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the jquery selector..

```
('#grouplist')
```

should be

```
$('#grouplist option')
```

Comment: How come it skipped the loop entirely after adding the dollar sign selector?

Comment: updated my answer, add the 'option' to loop through the items

Comment: I thought it was working but it's not, even adding option it still ignores the loop, it goes to the each line and then jumps past the loop despite items being in the listbox. I'll post a separate question since this is a different issue I think.